# Unable to interact with dialog box using selenium in Python

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, dialog

I am using "Python-3.4.1 32 bit" on "Windows 7 64 bit" machine with "Selenium" using "Firefox 33". I am trying to automate downloading a "CSV" file from a secured website after furnishing the necessary credentials.
I have written the required code to navigate to the correct element to initiate the download of the file but I am stuck when Firefox gives the download box (Dialog box title: Opening export.csv, "Open with" and "Save File" options as radio buttons with "OK" and "Cancel" as buttons). I want the file to be downloaded automatically and for that I have tried the following codes without success:

```
from selenium import webdriver
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",False)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",2)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir", "C:\\Users\\arun\\Downloads")
fp.set_preference("browser.download.downloadDir", "C:\\Users\\arun\\Downloads")
fp.set_preference("browser.download.defaultFolder", "C:\\Users\\arun\\Downloads")
fp.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk',"text/csv")
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile", "CONTENT-TYPE")
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","CONTENT-TYPE")

driver = webdriver.Firefox(fp)
driver.get("http://website-url.com")
```

and then click on the button to start the download. But, it still shows the dialog box. I even tried handling it as an alert and tried:

```
alert = driver.switch_to_alert()
alert.accept()
```

but this always gave an exception of alert not found which led me to the conclusion that it might not be a JavaScript functionality after all but rather a web element.

What do I do to get this downloaded automatically without the dialog box interaction (the way it's handled in Google Chrome browsers)

Thanks for your help and time
Cheers!

Comment: Have you tried with implementing some wait before catching the alert?

Comment: Hey Saifur, yes I have waited more than sufficient amount of time for the alert to appear but the code to catch an alert always raises the exception that "no alert found". Searching around on the Internet gave me the clue that it might not be a JavaScript alert but rather a web element alert.

Answer (score 0):

You set `browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk` to `text/csv` and then two lines later you set it to `CONTENT-TYPE`.

According to [this page](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Firefox_:_FAQs_:_About:config_Entries) this preference is interpreted as a list of MIME types. `CONTENT-TYPE` is not a valid MIME type and it has no other special meaning. You want to remove the 2nd assignment to `browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk`. You probably also don't want the assignment to `browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile`.

Once, your `browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk` is set properly, you should not have to worry about accepting a dialog box.

Comment: what if the server is not assigning the correct MIME type for the file that is being downloaded? The file I am downloading is of type: "text/csv" and in Firefox when the dialog box appears, "Do this automatically for files like this from now on" check box is greyed out.

Comment: And I tried: `code`from selenium import webdriver
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",False)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",2)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir", "C:\\Users\\arun\\Downloads")
fp.set_preference("browser.download.downloadDir", "C:\\Users\\arun\\Downloads")
fp.set_preference("browser.download.defaultFolder", "C:\\Users\\arun\\Downloads")
fp.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk',"text/csv")`code` but it is still displaying the dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium doesn't allow interaction with dialog windows (Save As dialog windows, for example). selenium is a web driver, so it only interacts with the browser.

I recommend using pywinauto and pywin32. It is a form of windows automation.

The problem is that selenium will "pause" while the dialog window is up, so to achieve this, the only way  I know would be to write two scripts. The first would be the selenium / web automation process, and the other one the windows automation using pywinauto and/or pywin32.

You can then call the windows automation script at the end of the selenium/web automation script by:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call("python C:\Python27\Scripts\windowsAutomation.py", shell=True)
```

One more thing, I am using FireFox 31

Answer (score 0):

You can try with Chrome chrome browser if all else fails. Chrome will not ask for download location but you have to enable multiple file download and set a save location